Calculating a definite improper integral - part 2
This question is regarding my previous question on the site. I want to calculate the following integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p(1+x)^{-p-1}}{r+sx}dx, p,r,s\in \mathbb{R}^+$$
according to the formulation for ${}_2F_1$ in DLMF we have
$$F\left(a,b;c;z\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(c\right)}{\Gamma\left(b\right)\Gamma\left(c-b%
\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{b-1}\left(t+1\right)^{a-c}}{\left(t-zt+1%
\right)^{a}}\,\mathrm{d}t, \Re c>\Re b > 0, \vert\text{arg} \left(1-z\right)\vert<\pi$$
therefore I concluded that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p(1+x)^{-p-1}}{r+sx}dx = \frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{r\Gamma(p+2)} {}_2F_1\left( 1,p+1,p+2,1-\frac{s}{r} \right)$$
However, when I use Mathematica to find the answer, I get the following one
$$ \frac{\, _2F_1\left(1,1;1-p;\frac{r}{s}\right)}{p s}+\frac{\pi  \csc (\pi  p) \left(\frac{s}{r}-1\right)^{-p}}{r-s} $$
Are these answers equivalent?!
Here is the command I used in Mathematica
Integrate[x^p*(1 + x)^(-1 - p)/(r + s*x), {x, 0, Infinity}]

Thank you!
